# Upload multiple files and access camera

Tags: html, ios, file-upload, upload

I can't seem to combine both options of selecting multiple files and accessing the camera on iOS at the same time.

This works with multiple files but does not offer the option to take a photo:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple capture="camera"/>
```

This offers both options but will not allow multiple uploads

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple capture="camera"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues has resolved itself with the latest iOS

Comment: This answer would deserve an upvote if the iOS version number was added.